# htaccess rewrite and redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have developed new site but I'm like to mantain some page adreesses already indexed on google.
Google had indexed in this way:
mysite.com/test-page/ (with slash at the end)

I have addedd on htaccess this conditions to cut off php extension when browsing:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Rewrite rule cute off .php extension from page:

```
mysite.com/test-page
```

For this i can't access page from google url

Exist a way to add redirect
from: mysite.com/test-page/
to: mysite.com/test-page
??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it touches more on maintaining a site as a webmaster than programming. You might be able to find an answer on webmasters.stackexchange.com (this comes up quite frequently there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

This will see the slash in the incoming request, but will not pass it to the resultant file-name.